# npm: How to install npm GitHub repositories with specific ssh keys?

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, ssh

I have a package.json with two private GitHub repositories. They both have to use a different SSH deploy key. For Git repositories without npm, this can be handled with a host in `.ssh/config`, for example:

```
Host repo1.github.com
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo1

Host repo2.github.com
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo2
```

Then in `.git/config` of repo1, I would have:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@repo1.github.com:org/repo1.git
```

Now, I thought I could just use the same trick for npm dependencies:

```
npm install "git+ssh://git@repo1.github.com/org/repo1.git#commit-hash" --save
```

Unfortunately, this will give me:

```
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "ssh:": ssh://git@repo1.github.com/org/repo1.git#commit-hash
```

If I use instead and the ssh right key is loaded:

```
npm install "git+ssh://git@github.com/org/repo1.git#commit-hash" --save
```

Then it works as expected. However, this is not a solution since I want to be able to run `npm install` and then it will have to use two different keys.

How can this be solved?